# How to weight a label by two parameters?

Tags: weights

I'm doing some labelling of time-series in preparation for ML.

However I'm not sure what approach I should use if I want to weight a label by two parameters ?

To keep it simple, let's say my label is `buy/sell`.

Now, clearly if I only had one variable `x` representing trend or whatever, I could either do a naïve binary labelling of `buy/sell` or I could bin the `x` variables into e.g. quartiles and label `buy/sell` accordingly, e.g. `{-2,-1,0,1,2}` based on what quartile `x` was in.

However what if I had a second variable `y` that should also be taken into account when determining the "strength" of the label ? i.e. the combined effect of `x`+`y` determine the "strength" of the label.

Variables `x` and `y` are continuous and so would inherently need some sort of transformation as part of the pre-label weighting process.  I mentioned binning above, but clearly if there are better ways I'm open to suggestions.